# How to develop plugin for microsoft office

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Hi my name is Aytekin.

I've been doing research for a while about develop extension or plugin for microsoft word.

But i still dont sure how is developing.

I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start here: [Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins).